# confirm validation for group of fields using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with address fields street, city, state, zipcode and I have another group with same field as confirm address. I want to apply the **equalTo** plugin option between address and confirm address in [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).  Also looking for group error message for this confirm case as below.

Form modal

```
Address

   street
   city
   state
   zipcode


Confirm Address

   street                    > error : Your address is not matching 
   city
   state
   zipcode
```

Comment: forgot to add `html` and `js`?

Comment: I thought it's generic, okay try to create fiddle

Comment: yes it is. thats why i am asking you to be specific in the problem your are facing. looking forward for your fiddle :)

Comment: @CerlinBoss: here is the form [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vk71kg59/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/vk71kg59/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#addressForm").validate({
        group:{
            address : "street city state zipcode",
            confirm_address : "street1 city1 state1 zipcode1",
        },
        rules: {
            street: {
                required: true
            },
            city: {
                required: true
            },
            state: {
                required: true
            },
            zipcode: {
                required: true
            },
            street1: {
                required: true,
                equalTo : "#street"
            },
            city1: {
                required: true,
                equalTo : "#city"
            },
            state1: {
                required: true,
                equalTo : "#state"
            },
            zipcode1: {
                required: true,
                equalTo : "#zipcode"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's easier than I think. It all about message grouping. good one. thanks

Comment: Your `group` option is not doing anything, because it's really called `groups`.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups